# Uncaught Error: MUI: makeStyles is no longer exported from

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I started getting this error after migrating to react version 18

`makeStyles.js:3 Uncaught Error: MUI: makeStyles is no longer exported from @mui/material/styles. You have to import it from @mui/styles.`

I have looked through the docs and tried different things but it didn't work.
How do I make this work?

here is my code:

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";



export default function Program() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [programData, setProgramData] = useState([]);

  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      display: "flex",
      flexWrap: "wrap",
      justifyContent: "space-around",
      overflow: "hidden",
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    },

    image: {
     height: "72%",
     width: "530px",
     objectFit: "cover",
     paddingBottom: 3,
   },
 }));
 useEffect(() => {
   axios
     .get("https://cryptic-shelf-72177.herokuapp.com/programs/api")
     .then((response) => {
      setProgramData([...response.data]);
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
     });
 }, []);

const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("xs"));
const classes = useStyles();

return (
  <div className={classes.root} style={{ padding: "3vw" }}>
    <ImageListItem key="Subheader" style={{ height: "auto" }}></ImageListItem>
    <ImageList
      rowHeight={550}
      cols={matches ? 1 : 3}
      className={classes.gridList}
      gap={12}
      style={{ background: "#A52A2A     " }}
     >
     {programData.length > 0 &&
      programData.map((tile, index) => {
        return (
          <ImageListItem
            key={Math.floor(Math.random() * new Date().getTime())}
            component={Link}
            to={"/programs/" + tile._id + "/programcomments"}
            style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
          >
            <img
              src={tile.programImage}
              alt={tile.title}
              class={classes.image}
            />
            <ImageListItemBar
              titlePosition="top"
              title={tile.title}
            // style={{ height: 400 }}
            />

            <Typography
              paragraph
              style={{
                borderBottom: "2px solid",
                background: "white",
                padding: 7,
              }}
            >
              {tile.description.substring(0, 222)}..
            </Typography>
          </ImageListItem>
        );
      })}
  </ImageList>
</div>
);
}
```

Everything was working fine until i migrated to React version 18, and made some material us changes that comes with React version 18 and materialui 5

Comment: Refer this it's probably deprecated https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

- Remove all dependencies by deleting node-modules folder in your project.
- Open a new terminal and run 'npm install'.

(Those two instructions above are optional)

- Since there has been a major change moving from Mui v4 to v5, makeStyles() is deprecated, so that you have to use styled() function instead, and import it from '@emotion/styled';

Example:

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';


const useStyles = styled(theme => ({
    root: {
        //Your styling rules
    }
}))
```

Take a look at the following link as well, thanks for @TeslaDelMar 's answer:

https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/uabs6g/material_ui_react_18/

Good luck!

Comment: This is the correct solution I needed to get rid of `@mui/styles` since it's incompatible with React.js 18.

Answer (score 1):

Due to a significant update from Mui version 4 to version 5, the `makeStyles()` function is now considered outdated. As a result, you should utilize the `styled()` function instead, which can be imported from `@mui/material`

This worked for me by REPLACING

```
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
```

by

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material';
```